# Adding to wishlist add single quantity

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, wishlist

When the user adds a product to wishlist then the product's quantity should not be passed. In the wishlist the product should have single quantity.

Answer (score 0):

When you will add product in wishlist you should add Qty in qty box.

If you add qty 10, in wishlist passed 10 qty.